# Set One Page To Have No ui-layout Panes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-layout

On most pages in my app, I have the north/east/south/west panes showing with jQuery UI Layout. On one page, I do not want any panes to show. I have added the following code to this one page, but the four panes still show:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        myLayout = $('body').layout({
            closable:           true
        ,   north__initClosed:  true
        ,   north__initHidden:  true
        ,   south__initClosed:  true
        ,   south__initHidden:  true
        ,   west__initClosed:   true
        ,   west__initHidden:   true
        ,   east__initClosed:   true
        ,   east__initHidden:   true
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why not just remove the `.layout` call all together?

Comment: I tried setting .layout to "", but it throws off the layout of the central pane then. I spent all day yesterday trying to adjust the CSS for this page, but was getting tangled in a rat's nest with adding the necessary stylesheet files and cloning alternate versions of other stylesheets.